# Windows 10 Unistack Service Group hogging CPU to 40% or more

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage

CPU is in high load, consuming battery and with the fan always on. Examining Task Manager, I can see the Unistack Service Group taking 40%-45% of load. Specs of machine: Windows 10 Pro 64 bits on Intel Core I5 with 8 GB RAM. There is no way to stop this: Unistack services group did not exist in Services Panel or from Task Manager is disabling to kill the task. ¿How do I stop or fix this problem?

Comment: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2792568/service-host-unistack-cpu.html

Comment: Thanks Moab but my problem is no related to running inside a virtual machine, so I can not give a new CPU to the execution environment.

Comment: Hi Fidel, can you clearly state what your question is? It isn't clear to me even though you are suggesting that the load is too high.

Answer (score 12):

The `Unistack Service Group` is part of the `Windows Store` and this happens when you get App Updates. To "disable" the usage, [disable the automatic App update](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6664-store-update-apps-automatically-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) in the Store options

[image]

and check for updates on your own and install them if you don't do work and you can ignore the higher CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

I found this is being caused by using the Mail and Calendar App in Windows 10.  Stop using those and your CPU usage goes down.  Need to wait for a fix from Microsoft.

Comment: nice pointer. turning mail's live tile off in the start menu is helping